# How to get a Mobile Optimized Website in the App store?

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

Im getting pressure to get a jqm website i did to be accessible from the app store.  Is this even possible?  I've heard that some people just develop an app that launches the website as a go between, but I havent been able to confirm that approach yet..?

I know you can always add the site to the home screen (aka a web app) but the client wants it searchable on the app store...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Apple reject "mobile web shell" applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478848/does-apple-reject-mobile-web-shell-applications)

Comment: Note the "simply web sites bundled as apps" reason for rejection pointed out there. Apple no longer accepts applications that are just wrappers for websites on the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook seems to have built their own PhoneGap like architecture that powers their mobile apps. But they use native where necessary and might also be displaying stuff in web views directly.  http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2011/09/how-facebook-mobile-was-design.php

Answer (score 1):

There are several frameworks out there, the only one I am familiar with is PhoneGap. Basically PhoneGap allows you to wrap your HTML/CSS/JavaScript website in native code to allow it to run as a native application. You can use a single code-base to deploy to: Android, iOS, Blackberry, Windows Mobile, and a couple others.

PhoneGap is free and was recently bought by Adobe and contributed to the Apache Software Foundation.

The performance implications of going this route (rather than creating an app from native code) are that you don't get fully native performance or full access to the native APIs. If you just want to get your website out there though, this is a great way to do it since you can maintain one code-base and deploy across multiple OSes.

You **can** have your cake and eat it too.

PhoneGap - http://phonegap.com

Comment: Ill look into it, I assume you still need to have a apple developers license and go through the difficult approval process?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to take what you have is to create a container app that is essentially a UIWebView with some kind of control bar (if necessary) that allows your users to go back and forth just like they do in mobile safari. Unfortunately this leads to a bad impression for users, they're expecting a native app but are just getting your website in a container that has less functionality than Mobile Safari provided them unless you extend it further than what I described.