# How to build native web apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to build a native app for iPhone which should be available in the App Store. A lot of the content is like an ordinary webpage with a bounce of text. A lot of this text has to be changed frequently, so I'm thinking that a web app would be a better alternative for this.

How is the standard procedure for making an web app? Currently I'm thinking that the entire app could be build using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (anything better?) and then I'll just create a simple native iOS application with a web browser pointing to this page (m.domain.com).

Is this how this should be done or are there better solutions for this? I've been looking at PhoneGap, but it seems that it embeds the HTML/CSS into the native application, which means that we have to update the app in App Store when there are changes in the content.

Comment: Apple does not allow simple apps that just wrapper website in an app. Since they can't be sure that if you change the site behind it the will still conform to the AppStore guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple will reject your app if it is only a wrapper for a web app. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5478893/1207152) previous post for more information.

Comment: @DennisMadsen You need to build other things instead of just a wrapper. Facebook uses a wrapper for the news feed but also has native features which make it acceptable in the app store.

Comment: They *may* reject it. Doesn't mean they *will*. My company shipped one of these in 2012; it was approved, along with its updates, and is still available in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap does embed HTML 5 and CSS into the application. It is however one of the best methods for creating an app using jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch. You have the choice of making a mobile website which the user can save to his/her phone, or the use of PhoneGap. Like other users have said, it isn't possible to create a simple wrapper that points to a website.