# phonegap - using external site as app - facebook login

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm building a app site running through phone gap. Phone gap simply checks the user has internet connection and loads an external web app into the frame. I can navigat through the site fine with no blibs but as soon as I try the login to Facebook (either PHP redirect or javascript SDK) the app suddenly gets its navbar back or opens a new window (javascript SDK).

Is there anyway I can prevent this?

regards

Answer (score 3):

It took some doing but using the ChildBrowser plugin, I've managed to login! (this is for android) I've used some code from a facebook connect plugin which didnt work for me, re wrote some stuffs so I could understand it and now works. Chears Juicy Scripter!

```
var fb_success = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
var fb_logout = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failed.html';
var fb_logout_ = 'http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=' + fb_logout;
var authorize_url = '';
var my_client_id = '##################';
var my_secret = '######################';
var my_type = 'user_agent';
var my_display = 'touch';
var token = false;
var fb_code = false;
var device_ready = false;
var ajax_url = '';

function logged_in(){
    // alert('do what you need to do!');
}
function fb_force_logout(){

}
function fb_auth_check(){
    console.log('fb_auth_check()');
    if( fb_code !== false ) {
        console.log('ajax test instigated...');
        ajax_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(my_client_id) + '&client_secret=' + encodeURIComponent(my_secret) + '&code=' + encodeURIComponent(fb_code) + '&redirect_uri=' + fb_success;
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(html){
                token = html.split("=")[1];
                console.log('success! token = ' + token);
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
                fb_init();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('there was an error...' + ajax_url);
                window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
function fb_track_redirects(loc){
    console.log('redirect tracked... ' + loc);
    if ( loc.indexOf(fb_success) >= 0 || loc.indexOf(fb_success) > -1 ) {
        fb_code = loc.match(/code=(.*)$/)[1]
        console.log('success redirect... fb_code=' + fb_code);
        fb_auth_check();
        window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
    } else if ( loc.indexOf(fb_logout) >= 0 || loc.indexOf(fb_logout) > -1 ) {
        window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
    }
}
function inner_init(){
    console.log('inner_init()');
    if( token === false ) {
        console.log('token was false...');
        authorize_url += "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?";
        authorize_url += "client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(my_client_id);
        authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(fb_success);
        authorize_url += "&display=" + encodeURIComponent(my_display);
        authorize_url += "&scope=publish_stream,offline_access";

        console.log('instigated location change...');
        window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){
            fb_track_redirects(loc);
        }
        console.log('open Facebbok login window');
        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(authorize_url);
    }else{
        logged_in();
    }
}
function fb_init(){
    console.log('fb_init()');
    if( device_ready === false ) {
        console.log('first device run...');
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            device_ready = true;
            console.log('device ready...');
            inner_init();
        }, false);
    }else{
        inner_init();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').bind('click', function(){
        fb_init();
        return false;
    })
});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works for all apps native or web without patching the SDK code.

This is probably can be done, but will require digging into code. The question is do you really need it? This is a desired behavior.

You can try to use PhoneGap Facebook plugin and enable Single Sign On so native Facebook App if exists will be opened instead of browser to authenticate the user.

BTW,
Apps that are just external sites wrapped mostly rejected in app store.

**Update:**
Where is some points that may be also helpful in [answer (by Facebook employee)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7835590/155033) to similar question [How can I use an access token to circumvent FB.login()](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7835381/how-can-i-use-an-access-token-to-circumvent-fb-login).

Also have a look on [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) PhoneGap plugin (and [Example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser/FBConnectExample)).

Comment: Why are they?   how do you know this?

Comment: After a slight bit of reading I think you're wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478848/does-apple-reject-mobile-web-shell-applications you have no idea what this game does, you just assume its a "simple site"

Comment: @PhilJackson, Re-read the [answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5478893/155033), this is exactly what I said in BTW. And this was a bit out of scope of the question.

Comment: Ok, java is old school and I haven't the time to learn it from scratch. Phonegap seems to be the next best thing for me. I have years of experience in html, css, jquery, PHP and a few others. I have a good idea for a turn based game to be ran through facebook. I want the professional apearance and apeal of a native app, i.e. no address bar, signal bar and so on. Constant portrait view, splash page and so on...

Comment: ...I have managed to figure all this out in 2 days. My only problem is the loggin in which is done at the external server end. when I tried to load cordova-1.5.0.js into the page servered from the server, I just got loads of popups, seemed to be in reference with the polling thats going off every second or so, therefore it was my asumption (due to I couldn't find anything about it) that the phonegap js could only be loaded localy which then lead me to that more than likely the FB plugin would be no good...

Comment: @PhilJackson, I've updated my answer to provide a bit more links related to subject which may help.

Comment: I'm going to make this as answer but it's not. The childBrowser plugin works which I believe will lead me to my answer (will post it when I do)

Comment: @PhilJackson, don't do it then. If you feel it doesn't answer the question leave it as is.

Comment: unticked... but I'll be back as I'm nearly there!