# iPhone start screen latency

Tags: iphone, performance, latency

Im wrapping a html5 website in a native app. The app splash screen appears for a sec then a white page appears, I decided to add an image view that have the same image as the splash screen to fill this white screen and I hide this intermediate image once the websites download all the jquery and CSS. However, this screen lasts for really long time (up to 30 sec.) so I thought that it may be due to the jquery and CSS large buddle downloading time. So create a page which has and image and a redirect js(non library) statement and found that redirects so fast. I cannot understand why, anybody have an explanation

Comment: How long does the page take when you load the website from Safari?

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour when attaching a web view

Comment: What you can do is add a progress bar or a spinner so it can be more user friendly, but that white screen means it's downloading stuff from the web

Comment: I actually added a spinner and also an image that hides when the web view finishes loading. But how to add a progress bar. Web view does not give any info about how much percentage it did load as far as I know, am I mistaking here?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider that your app plans may run afoul of App Store guidelines:

[Apple can reject mobile web shell apps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5478893/410867)

Comment: I found that if you provide html5 website that is useful, and look like an app, they accept it. I made my menu system look like the iOS menu system and they passed it through. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Getting through once doesn't mean they won't take a different stance later. We encountered problems with subscriptions, but the lesson is the same. Just because Apple accepted it once doesn't mean they won't enforce the rule strictly later.

Comment: You are definitely right! They might take different stance later but for now they accepting my applications in which I simple use a wrapper for html5 mobile site. I like this approach because of the great flexibility html5 gives in updating the look and feel.