# Get webb application to app store

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Apple reject “mobile web shell” applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478848/does-apple-reject-mobile-web-shell-applications)

i am wondering if it is possible to make a mobile webpage and than making a IOS app in xcode just having a full screen browser view loading the mobile webpage.

I heard someone saying that apple does not allow apps that one includes a webpage, is this true?

Comment: It is true. Apps that simply load up a webpage are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true. http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, are **simply web sites bundled as apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be
>   rejected

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your application will most likely be reject for this.

I recommend taking your existing files and using something like http://phonegap.com/ and deploy your web application to multiple stores. This works because your assets are baked into the application.