# How do you wrap a web app as iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, web-applications

I have this [web app](https://github.com/bodokaiser/nearby) which works great on mobile browsers however I would like to allow this app being downloaded as "native app" through the apple app store.

My app basically consists out of three files which it serves to the client:

- index.html
- build.js
- build.css

My research so far came to the conclusion that it is possible to do this by creating a web view with objective-c which executes the web app. Additionally you may use SDKs like phone gap to use native APIs (which is not required in this case).

Unfortunately I do not find a lot information on this by google, so I have following questions:

1. What is the "keyword" I am looking for (whats the term for "wrapping html app in object-c")?
2. Do I have to change the urls in my build.js (or can I overwrite current origin)?
3. Is there anything else I would need to change in build.js?
4. Are there any problems I should consider?

Comment: Term you are looking for is "mobile web shell" and there is a risk at least on [iOS front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478848/does-apple-reject-mobile-web-shell-applications). Apps developed using Phonegap are allowed, but they are more than just few files. I think they have a lot of offline features apart from the web based features.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Will apple approve your app? Defiantly not.

From the App Store Review Guidelines:

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, **are simply web sites bundled as apps**,
>   or do not provide any lasting
>   entertainment value may be rejected

1. web shell, web app
2. Changing the urls for local path would work.
3. Depends on how build.js was written.
4. The above.

**So what can you do?**

Think how to improve your app with native code and add some functionality to it.

Focusing on the native code will help. If you'll submit an app that opens a `UIWebView` and that's it apple will 100% reject it.

I wrote an app for my company that wrapped a web app inside a `UIWebView` but had a lot of native code that would sniff the current `UIWebView` url and triggered functions accordingly. (Opened the cam, recorded audio, uploaded stuff to the server) so in the end it was very hybrid.

Apple rejected it with the claim that the user still sees only a webpage. I had to add a lot of other visible functionality in order for it to get approved.

Comment: Why are you assuming that just because it's a web app it has no "lasting entertainment value?" Apps, either web or native both have the opportunity to build entertaining and engaging experiences for users.

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald I think you need to read the answer again. I wasn't assuming, this is a quote from the "App Store Review Guidelines". The relevant sentence is bold. The sentence that you quoted is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Right you are. Sorry, I think I let my frustration with Apple get the best of me on my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems like a very general and appealing idea for developers but as far as I know, these sort of applications are not taken very sportingly by apple app reviewer.

When I say these sort, I actually mean application which calls webpages as browser. For these type of calling browser is perfect.

Now lets talk about development. If you want to start with development then [this is your takeoff place](http://phonegap.com/developer/). As you have all your skills with HTML, JS and CSS, you'll rock with this development platform called **Phonegap**. and the beauty of this platform is you can import same build for other mobile platform as well.

Looking forward for some worthy applications. Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but the answers above may be out of date.  [The new app store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) do not include the quoted language about "websites bundled as apps."  Perhaps Apple has eased up on this issue?

Comment: Please include the relevant guidelines in your answer.  Link-based answers are discouraged as the links are susceptible to change, rending your answer inaccurate or wrong in the future.

Comment: I still see a reference to not just wrapping a website here:4.2 Minimum Functionality
Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn't provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, or is just plain creepy, it may not be accepted. Apps that are simply a song or movie should be submitted to the iTunes Store. Apps that are simply a book or game guide should be submitted to the iBooks Store.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned that repackaged websites are not acceptable (Sep 2019). https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality

Answer (score -1):

You can use a new tool called [Natively](https://buildnatively.com) It helps to wrap web apps to mobile native. They also have JS SDK to integrate with native features & pretty clear documentation.